# Pytorch My loss updated but my accuracy keep in exactly same value

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

When i trained my images with Resnet model, my loss in both val and train was updated while my train, val accuracy did not, they stay in the same number. What happens, please help me?

Thank you a lot.

> Finished training epoch 0: Train loss: 0.6814049482345581, Train Acc:
> 59.35077667236328. Val loss: 0.7146084308624268, Val Acc: 60.75581359863281 Finished training epoch 1: Train loss: 0.6787809729576111, Train Acc: 59.35077667236328.  Val loss: 0.7859861254692078, Val Acc: 60.75581359863281

Here is my code:

```
#Create model
model = resnet50(
    num_seg_classes=2,
    no_cuda=False)
 
model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0,1,2,3]).cuda()
net_dict = model.state_dict() 

pretrain_path = os.path.join("H:\MinhBPL\ADNIDatabase\MedicalNet_pytorch_files2",
                            "resnet_50.pth")
print ('loading pretrained model {}'.format(pretrain_path))
pretrain = torch.load(pretrain_path)
pretrain_dict = {k: v for k, v in pretrain['state_dict'].items() if k in net_dict.keys()}
net_dict.update(pretrain_dict)
model.load_state_dict(net_dict)

class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value
       Imported from https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L247-L262
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count
def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
    """Computes the precision@k for the specified values of k"""
    maxk = max(topk)
    batch_size = target.size(0)

    _, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
    pred = pred.t()
    correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).cuda().expand_as(pred))

    res = []
    for k in topk:
        correct_k = correct[:k].view(-1).float().sum(0)
        res.append(correct_k.mul_(100.0 / batch_size))
    return res

def train(trainloader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch, use_cuda):
    model.train()
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    data_time = AverageMeter()
    losses = AverageMeter()
    top = AverageMeter()
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Start training epoch {epoch}')
    for (inputs, targets) in tqdm(trainloader):
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)
        if use_cuda:
            inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
        inputs, targets = torch.autograd.Variable(inputs), torch.autograd.Variable(targets)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        prec= accuracy(outputs.data, targets.data, topk=(1,))
        losses.update(loss, inputs.size(0))
        top.update(prec[0], inputs.size(0))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()
        
    print(f'Finished training epoch {epoch}: Train loss: {losses.avg}, Train Acc: {top.avg}, Batch time: {batch_time} ')
    return (losses.avg, top.avg)

def test(testloader, model, criterion, epoch, use_cuda):
    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    data_time = AverageMeter()
    losses = AverageMeter()
    top = AverageMeter()    
    
    model.eval()
    
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Start val epoch {epoch}')
    with torch.no_grad():
        for (inputs, targets) in tqdm(testloader):
            data_time.update(time.time() - end)
            if use_cuda:
                inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
            inputs, targets = torch.autograd.Variable(inputs, volatile=True), torch.autograd.Variable(targets)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
            prec= accuracy(outputs.data, targets.data, topk=(1,))
            losses.update(loss, inputs.size(0))
            top.update(prec[0], inputs.size(0))
            batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
            end = time.time()
        print(f'Finished training epoch {epoch}: Val loss: {losses.avg}, Val Acc: {top.avg}, Batch time: {batch_time} ')
        return (losses.avg, top.avg)

use_cuda = True
graph_loss = {}
graph_acc = {}
graph_loss['train'] = []
graph_loss['val'] = []
graph_acc['train'] = []
graph_acc['val'] = []

best_acc = 0
for epoch in range(100):
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    train_loss, train_acc = train(train_dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch, use_cuda)
    test_loss, test_acc = test(val_dataloader, model, criterion, epoch, use_cuda)
    graph_loss['train'].append(train_loss)
    graph_loss['val'].append(test_loss)
    graph_acc['val'].append(train_acc)
    graph_acc['val'].append(test_acc)
    is_best = test_acc > best_acc
    if is_best:
        best_acc = max(test_acc, best_acc)
        saveModel('savedModel')
```

Comment: What are the shape of `output` and `target`, the two arguments of your `accuracy` function?

Comment: @Ivan the output shape is (N,num_classes) where N is number of images per batch. Target is (N,1) which contain the label

Answer (score 0):

<s>Move `optimizer.zero_grad()` before the forward pass.
It makes computed gradients be zero, therefore there is no update in your model.</s>

According to @Ivan, this is the wrong answer.

Comment: As long as the `zero_grad` call is before the `backward` call, then it's fine whether that is before the inference or after.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I should update this answer